Show that $\exists x \forall y R(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x \exists y R(x,y)$ is not provable by natural deduction
Problem: Show that the formula $$\exists x \forall y R(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x \exists y R(x,y)$$ is not provable by natural deduction.
So far: First thought that came to mind was simply considering the natural numbers with an order relation to give a counter-example (considering an assignment such that $s(x)=0$). However now $R(x,x)$ is not valid, since obviously $0\not<0$. I can think of countless examples, but they all get stuck on this reflexivity.

You have to precise the universe you are in. You said there exists x but you don't say where.

The whole point is giving an example of a universe and relation where the implication fails. Hence it's not yet specified

Hint: There is a counterexample whose universe has just two elements.

The premise entails reflexivity for $x$. But to deny the conclusion, you cannot have reflexivity for every element. So, you cannot chose a relation that is reflexive or irreflexive. You have to come up with one that is reflexive for some values and irreflexive for others.

Thanks, figured it out.
